# Symfony 4: Login not working for token, but working for username and password

Tags: php, symfony, authentication, token

My problem trace is:

> Type error: Argument 4 passed to

> Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\UsernamePasswordToken::__construct()
> must be of the type array, null given, called in
> ...\vendor\symfony\security\Core\Authentication\Provider\UserAuthenticationProvider.php
> on line 90

and the thing is:

- When I try to log-in, username and password work, but not the token, and in my entity, token is defined as attended, as an array

```
/**
* @ORM\Column(type="array")
*/
private $role;
```

same for getter and setter,

so if I understand well, it tries to access to the array of the construct Authentication class, which is the role, but it says that the role is null.
so this is my login class:

```
$error = $authenticationUtils->getLastAuthenticationError();
$lastUsername = $authenticationUtils->getLastUsername();

if ($this->getUser()) {
        $this->addFlash('danger', 'You are already identified on TCELab');
        return $this->redirectToRoute("default");
    }

return $this->render('user/sign_in.html.twig', array(
        'last_username' => $lastUsername,
        'error' => $error,
    ));
```

normally this should work. How can I make this work?

Answer (score 2):

In your User entity, set a default value for your `roles` attributes.

```
/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="array")
 */
private $roles = [];
```

or

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->roles = [];
}
```

Comment: Thank You I've found, it was because I've name role and note role(s) ....